# Single sign on solution

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

Hi I am using **CAS** for SSO. But problem is that i want reset password,register new user on **CAS** login screen.
**Does CAS provide these services or i have to implement?**
Or Any other SSO solution exist which fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAS is just a SSO frontend to your existing identity management solution (database, LDAP etc). It does not include any identity management features itself (create user account, reset password etc). I have recently been using the [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com) platform which is a full identity management solution and so far I am pretty impressed. I believe Atlassians [Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview) also includes this although I have not used it. There are probably other products out there as well.

Both of these are commercial products although they are both free for the first 50 users. Crowd is a traditional standalone platform which you download, install and configure but Cloudseal is a hosted service so there is no installation and less config.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly modify the spring weblog and login page to allow for the functionality that of course you'd have to implement. You should also ask the question on @cas-user mailing list to see if a similar need in the community has been implemented by other users which you may be able to take advantage of. I remember only recently someone raised the same question to the list and there was a bit of interest in getting this feature developed and integrated. You may want to revisit the topic on the mailing list.

Hope this helps.